Passing fields to a nested model with model_validate() in Pydantic V2
Consider I have the following SQLAlchemy DB model:
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(sa.String(64), nullable=True, index=True)
    email: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(sa.String(128), nullable=True)

And I use the following Pydantic V2 models to serialize user objects:
class PrivateDataSerializer(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    username: str | None
    email: str | None


class ProfileSerializer(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    id: int
    private_data: PrivateDataSerializer

As you can see, I put the username & email fields in a nested model.
My goal is to be able to load a user object into the Pydantic model using:
ProfileSerializer.model_validate(user)

However, I couldn't find the way to properly configure a mapping for fields in private_data.
I have some experience with Django DRF and using it's ModelSerializer you can specify source="*" for a nested model for this purpose:
class PrivateDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email"]


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    private_data = PrivateDataSerializer(source="*")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["id", "private_data"]

So, how could I achieve the same result with Pydantic?

Does this answer your question? How to change a pydantic list of objects into list of strings?

You also need to provide id for ProfileSerializer. Pydantic works by how you define your schema. Currently ProfileSerializer's schema doesn't match the user object itself.
This would work:
user = User(10, "foo", "bar")
print(ProfileSerializer.model_validate({"id": user.id, "private_data": user}))

or:
user = User(10, "foo", "bar")
private_data = PrivateDataSerializer.model_validate(user)
print(ProfileSerializer(id=user.id, private_data=private_data))


Using my favourite classmethods)
This is the most flexible way to do what you want. You can also use model_validate inside, but not sure you need it in this case.
class ProfileSerializer(BaseModel):
    id: int
    private_data: PrivateDataSerializer

    @classmethod
    def from_db_model(cls, model: User) -> "ProfileSerializer":
        """Build Profile Serializer from db model."""

        return cls(
            id=model.id,
            private_data=PrivateDataSerializer(
                username=model.username,
                email=model.email,
            )
        )

serializer = ProfileSerializer.from_db_model(model=user)

I've answered similar question here:
How to change a pydantic list of objects into list of strings?
